# Filer taxonomy posts by current category

Tags: custom-taxonomy, link-category

I have a custom taxonomy 'where' and I am using this code to get taxonomy terms on single.php

```
<?php echo get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'where', 'Where: ', ', ', '' ); ?>
```

How can I customize this code in a way if user click on 'where' terms, they should get posts of this taxonomy only from the current category.

Answer (score 0):

Use a **taxonomy.php** template?!

**taxonomy.php**

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php $term = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) ); ?>

<h1><?php echo $term->name; ?></h1>

<?php
global $query_string;
query_posts( $query_string . '&orderby=title&order=asc' );

if (have_posts()) : 
?>

<?php
while (have_posts()) : the_post();
?>

<h1><a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>

<?php endwhile; 
wp_reset_query();
?>

<?php endif; ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```