# Wordpress Taxonomy Menu

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, advanced-taxonomy-queries

I have got the following simple code.

```
<ul id="filter"><?php       
echo '<li class="active"><a href="#" class="all">All</a></li>';             
if ( $count > 0 ) {             
    foreach ( $mylinks as $mylink ) {
        echo '<li>'.'<a href="#" class="'. $mylink->slug .'" >';
        echo $mylink->name;
        echo "</a>";
        echo "</li>";
        }
    }   
?>
```

The above basically returns the following:

```
<ul class="filter">
<li class="active">
    <a class="all" href="#">All</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a class="education" href="#">Education</a>
</li>
<!-- Etc. --></ul>
```

What I want is to have the taxonomy terms, (i.e. say taxonomy Education to link to an independent page: http://website.com/education and on that page have all the custom post types with the taxonomy 'education' displayed on the page.

PS: Displaying the taxonomy terms is not a problem, the problem is linking the displayed taxonomy terms (in the code above) to an independent page (http://website.com/independent_page). This must happen all dynamically.

Is it possible? Please share your suggestions or links to tutorials.

One more question. What is the exact custom taxonomy URL? Is it http://website.com/taxonomy/education  ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood this correct, then you need a taxonomy.php file.

[LINK](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/72934/filer-taxonomy-posts-by-current-category/73042#73042)